# ParseUI activity code is not working

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to get ParseUI to work with my app.
I have imported the libs, sync with gradle and everything is workign fine. Till when I actually put the code for the activity to be initiated, I get error saying 'cannot resolve symbol build'.

```
public class Login_activity extends FragmentActivity  //implements Validator.ValidationListener
{

    ParseLoginBuilder builder = new ParseLoginBuilder(Login_activity.this);

    Login_activity(builder.build(), 0);
```

Actual code that I am supposed to use according to Parse docs

```
ParseLoginBuilder builder = new ParseLoginBuilder(MyActivity.this);
startActivityForResult(builder.build(), 0);
```

[image]

EDIT:
This is the updated code

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//

        //super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ParseLoginBuilder builder = new ParseLoginBuilder(Login_activity.this);

        startActivityForResult(builder.build(), 0);

    }
```

Comment: This is android studio.. where is Restart?

Comment: Yuva, the problem is clearly not with the environment, caches etc, the problem is that his code is not valid Java and is full of errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
Login_activity(builder.build(), 0);
```

is not valid Java. Your are trying to call the name of the class as if it was a method. I am not sure what you are trying to do (invoke the constructor? - which would not make sense for an Activity), but this code is incorrect. If you meant to call startActivityForResult, then do so, instead of substituting startActivityForResult with your class name, because doing so makes no sense.

EDIT:
Furthermore, you are adding lines of code to be executed directly in the class body, as opposed to inside a method. In Java, a class body can only contain declarations (which may include statements as part of an assignment) or static blocks of code, all other code must be part of a method.

```
class MyClass {
    ... you can only have declarations and assignments here

    public void someMethod() {
        ... actual code statements here
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer. Basically I don't understand why you don't just follow that code example and use startActivityForResult. What made you substitute startActivityForResult with Login_activity(...) ?

Comment: Even following the docs did not get me anywhere.. and the reason I changed it to my activity name is because Android Studio recommended it.

Comment: Well, in this case, Android Studio misinterpreted your intentions and made a bad suggestion. It probably thought you were trying to declare a constructor for your class. BTW, I now also see that the code you are writing is in the class body, not in a method. So that's why you got Android Studio confused. You have to put your code in an actual method, such as onCreate(...), you can't just put code directly in the class body. I updated my answer again.

Comment: Alright , good catch, but now when I add the code and run it it is not running at all.. I mean i dont see anything on the screen, expect that sucessfully built

Comment: Perhaps you should then accept my answer, close the question, and raise a new question.

Comment: TBH reputation doesn't interest me, but for the sake of SO readers, it gets very confusing if a question starts off with a compilation error, and then gets transformed into handling numerous follow up errors not related to the first problem. But thanks.